# add page number to pdf document (itextsharp)

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to add page numbers to the footer of the itextsharp pdf file.Im generating pdf from html (asp.net repeater).And Im using XMLWorkerHelper to parse the html content.I searched a lot but cant find anything useful to achive this.

Comment: Hmm, strange. How exactly did you search? Because when I visited the [following link](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=itextsharp+add+page+numbers&oq=itextsharp+add+page+numbers&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0.438.7461.0.7578.27.15.0.12.12.0.158.1445.11j4.15.0...0.0.xJrtHtJSBd0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d0f8cd49a0fc8cd2&biw=1440&bih=795) I got quite a reasonable amount of interesting pointers.

Comment: if you create document on the fly ,there is examples about adding page numbers .But im creating pdf document from the html in the page.I dont do any thing,i just get the html output of the repeater by this repeater.RenderControl property and parse it with xhtmlworkerhelp class.Shortly pdf document is being created by  xhtmlworkerhelp ,i dont involve in the details of the document.I hope i can tell what im doing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to open the PDF with `iTextSharp` and add the page numbers yourself. I did something like this a while back, here's my function that might give you a start.
The function adds the current page to the lower left, so you might have to place it somewhere else that fits your needs.

```
public static byte[] AddPageNumbers(byte[] pdf)
{
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
// we create a reader for a certain document
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
// we retrieve the total number of pages
int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
// we retrieve the size of the first page
Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

// step 1: creation of a document-object
Document document = new Document(psize, 50, 50, 50, 50);
// step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);
// step 3: we open the document

document.Open();
// step 4: we add content
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

int p = 0;
Console.WriteLine("There are " + n + " pages in the document.");
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    document.NewPage();
    p++;

    PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, page);
    cb.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);

    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    cb.BeginText();
    cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
    cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, +p + "/" + n, 7, 44, 0);
    cb.EndText();
}
// step 5: we close the document
document.Close();
return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! but ms.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length) is not necessary and has caused file corruption in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
var sourceFileList = new List<string>();

//add files to merge

int sourceIndex = 0;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFileList[sourceIndex]);
int sourceFilePageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;

Document doc = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(destinationFileName, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

PdfImportedPage page;
PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;                

int rotation;
while (sourceIndex < sourceFileList.Count)
{
    int pageIndex = 0;
    while (pageIndex < sourceFilePageCount)
    {
        pageIndex++;

        doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex));
        doc.NewPage();

        page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, pageIndex);
        rotation = reader.GetPageRotation(pageIndex);

        if (rotation.Equals(90 | 270))
            contentByte.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageIndex).Height);
        else
            contentByte.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
    }

    sourceIndex++;
    if (sourceIndex < sourceFileList.Count)
    {
        reader = new PdfReader(sourceFileList[sourceIndex]);
        sourceFilePageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;
    }
}

doc.Close();
```